# I have powershell function error, the not execute

Tags: powershell

I am a beginner in powershell script. I have a diskcap function to avoid retyping the text. but I get errors.

```
    Function DiskCap­ {
     return 
     (write-host "calcule de l'espace libre avant le nettoyage.")
     ($FreeSpace = (Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk | where { $_.DeviceID -eq $env:SystemDrive }).FreeSpace)
     ($yourdisk = Get-WmiObject Win32_volume)

      ForEach ($Item in $YourDisk) {
      "{0,-8} {1,2}" -f $Item.Name, (Format-DiskSize $Item.Capacity).phase
      } 
     }

 pause
 #Write-Host $(diskcap)
```

> [ERROR] diskcap : Le terme «diskcap» n'est pas reconnu comme nom d'applet de commande,  [ERROR] fonction, fichier de script ou
>   programme exécutable. Vérifiez l'orthographe du nom,  [ERROR] ou si un
>   chemin d'accès existe, vérifiez que le chemin d'accès est correct et 
>   [ERROR] réessayez. [ERROR] Au caractère
>   C:\Users\SoutienInformatique\Downloads\Ninite\CLEAN.ps1:53 : 15
>   [ERROR] +  Write-Host $(diskcap) [ERROR] +               ~~~~~~~
>   [ERROR]     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (diskcap:String)
>   [], CommandNotFoundEx  [ERROR]    ception [ERROR]     +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException [ERROR]

Comment: Why not post the error message in the question so that others can help you easier?

Comment: Please post the errors you get in their entirety. Also if you wrote Format-DiskSize and it might be related to the errors you're getting then post the source for it, if practical. I just googled Format-Disksize and I'm guessing you got it [here](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_function_format_disksize.htm). It's not too long so it shouldn't be a problem to add it to your post.

Comment: The error says that diskcap is not a function cmdlet...... Where do you call your function? I see a commented out call. You need to call the function _after_ it is declared is the right answer. Also, if possible, you need to post English translations of error as the SO is an English support site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code doesn't throw the "'diskcap' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet" error.

You don't need to add the write-host $(diskcap) at the end to get the output of the function. You can just call it. The parenthesis is also not nessecary around each statement.

```
function DiskCap­ {  
  write-host "calcule de l'espace libre avant le nettoyage." 
  $FreeSpace = (Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk | Where-Object { $_.DeviceID -eq $env:SystemDrive }).FreeSpace
  $yourDisk = Get-WmiObject Win32_volume 
  foreach ($Item in $yourDisk) 
  {
    "{0,-8} {1,2}" -f $Item.Name, (Format-DiskSize $Item.Capacity).phase
  } 
}

Pause
DiskCap­
```